# Query Builder giving a parameters bound error

Tags: yii

I'm using [Yii 1.1.15](http://www.yiiframework.com/download/) and am trying to create a query. but when i do i get a `no parameters where bound error` This is my code below. From the [doc](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/database.query-builder) it looks like i'm doing everything right.

```
   $user = Yii::app()->db->createCommand()
                    ->select()
                    ->from('ABC')
                    ->where('id=:id0 AND id=:id1 AND id=:id2', array(':id0'=> '07Q00G', ':id1'=>'07Q01A', ':id2'=>'07Q02A'))
                    ->execute();


CDbCommand failed to execute the SQL statement: SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: no parameters were bound. The SQL statement executed was: SELECT *
FROM `ABC`
WHERE id=:id0 AND id=:id1 AND id=:id2
```

also when i used `->query()` instead of `->execute()` it echo's this. and doesnt replace the variables

```
CDbDataReader Object ( [_statement:CDbDataReader:private] => PDOStatement Object ( [queryString] => SELECT * FROM `ABC` WHERE id=:id0 AND id=:id1 AND id=:id2 ) [_closed:CDbDataReader:private] => [_row:CDbDataReader:private] => [_index:CDbDataReader:private] => -1 [_e:CComponent:private] => [_m:CComponent:private] => )
```

Any idea what i'm missing here?

Comment: did you try `queryScaler()` or `queryRow();` ??

Comment: @SudhanshuSaxena yup, when i `print_r($user); die;` i get a blank page. nothing being printed / echoed

Comment: or is there another way to do this? by using variables? `:id0`

Comment: check the table again, is there any data which fulfill this conditions or not.You get the blank array that means the query is working like it should, check the table again and fire the query manually there and see any data is coming or not.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of **execute()** you should do `queryAll()`

so It should be

```
$user = Yii::app()->db->createCommand()
                    ->select()
                    ->from('ABC')
                    ->where('id=:id0 AND id=:id1 AND id=:id2', array(':id0'=> '07Q00G', ':id1'=>'07Q01A', ':id2'=>'07Q02A'))
                    ->queryAll();
```

Comment: when i `print_r()` i get `Array ( )`